# Python+Selenium reconstruct true HTML after executing javascript on page

Tags: javascript, python, forms, selenium

I have this super simple code running in selenium

```
<input name="X" id="unique" value="" type="text">

<script>
    document.getElementById("unique").value="123";
</script>
```

I am able to get input value`123` by calling
`driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("unique").value')`

but I am not able to get real HTML code with updated value "123"
using any of these methods

1. `driver.page_source` - no updated value
2. `driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`  no updated value
3. `driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById("unique").outerHTML")`  no updated value either

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the difference between `by calling driver.execute_script()` and `get real HTML code`?

Comment: I am getting ```<input name="X" id="unique" value="" type="text">```   but expecting ```<input name="X" id="unique" value="123" type="text">```

Comment: Is the value `123` visible on the webpage/frontend?

Comment: yes it is visible on frontend but not visible in developer tools/ inspect element

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try using regular Selenium `find_element` to get the attribute? The point of using Selenium is so that you can access their built-in functionality to do this for you. Javascript is just meant to be a workaround for unique issues.

This will fetch the `value` attribute on the `input` element you posted:

```
input_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='unique']").get_attribute("value")
```

This is functionally the same as `driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("unique").value')`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
document.getElementById("unique").setAttribute('value', '123');
```

This way will definitely update the DOM